# Treeview in Xaml for self created class

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, treeview

Can someone tell me how to generate a treeview in wpf for the following class?

I am trying for hours and hours, without any kind of success...

I have used the search funtionality and also google. but my case seems to be different, or i am to ....

```
namespace EIT_Base
{
public class LocationTreeAlsTree : IEnumerable,IEnumerator
    {
        // Integriere den Logger von NLog
        private static readonly Logger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

        // Eigenschaften der Klasse LocationTreeAlsTree
        public List<ComponentRef> Elements { get; set; }
        public int position = -1;

        public static List<ComponentRef> LoadUnits(IEnumerable<XElement> _componentenRef)
        {
            return _componentenRef.Select(x => new ComponentRef()
            {
                ID = Convert.ToInt32(x.Attribute("ref").Value),
                Children = LoadUnits(x.Elements("componentRef"))
            }).ToList();
        }

        public LocationTreeAlsTree(string _filename)
        {
            string locationtreeFile = _filename;
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(locationtreeFile, Encoding.UTF8);
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(reader);
            Elements = LoadUnits(doc.Descendants("componentRef"));
        }

        public IEnumerator GetEnumerator() { return this.Elements.GetEnumerator(); }

        public bool MoveNext() { position++; return (position < Elements.Count); }

        public void Reset() { position = -1; }

        public object Current { get { return Convert.ToInt32(Elements[position].ID); } }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're taking a route that's more complicated than what you actually need. Here is a basic way of achieving what it looks like you are attempting to achieve.

Add this to your XML:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding TopLevelElements}">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Elements}">
            <Grid>
                <!-- Bind display information for any given Element's xDocument or whatever you want -->
            </Grid>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

Then create some Element class which has an ObservableCollection of Elements (creating the recursive structure we want in a treeview):

```
public class Element 
{
    public ObservableCollection<Element> Elements = new ObservableCollection<Element>();

    public Element(string filename) 
    {
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(locationtreeFile, Encoding.UTF8);
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(reader);
        Elements = LoadUnits(doc.Descendants("componentRef"));
    }
}
```

Finally, define some top-level ObservableCollection of Element for your treeview to initially bind to:

```
public ObservableCollection<Element> TopLevelElements = new ObservableCollection<Element>();

public MainWindow() 
{
    TopLevelElements.Add(new Element("filename"));

    DataContext = this;

    InitializeComponent();
}
```

As you can see in the XML portion, the HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource is to Elements. Since each Element has an ObservableCollection of Elements, it will then draw out a treeview according to this object structure. You can reference properties of Element inside the HierarchicalDataTemplate XML structure.

Comment: i have tried to use you solution, it isn´t working. sorry for that.